# How to calculate phage infection rate from decreased PFU counts?

Tags: virology, infection, bacteriophage

Some experiments measured the effect of particular chemicals on the infectivity of lytic phages in terms of influence on the PFU/mL counts.

For example, the reduction of PFU/mL of exposed phages over controls might be 2 logs (let's say from 1000 PFU/mL in controls to 10 PFU/mL in exposed). If I knew the infection rate of the control phage (let's say 1), how can I calculate the infection rate of the exposed phages?

Thank you

Comment: I think you have a few problems here - first off would be that it should be PFU (plaque forming units); as CFU is for bacterial colony forming units. Second, assuming a standard concentration of bacteria, what do you think is measured by the PFU/ml?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have mistaken CFU with PFU, I have corrected the post.